# Did Jesus ever write anything?

Tags: jesus, authorship

I mean we got writing by matthew, mark, luke, etc. Where is writing by Jesus? Anything survive?

Did Jesus ever write anything that survives?

I am aware of a tradition that king of Edessa want to be healed and Jesus wrote back. However, that is dubious.

> There is an ancient letter that purports to have been written from
>   Jesus. It is known as, "The Letter to King Abgar." Abgar was a real
>   king who reigned from A.D. 9 to A.D. 46 in what is in modern- day
>   Turkey. As the story goes, King Abgar wrote first to Jesus requesting
>   a miracle.
>
> ```
> And when I heard all those things about you, I considered that you are either God himself who has come down from heaven to act like this,
> ```
>
> or that you are the Son of God doing such things. Therefore I am
>   writing to you and ask you to visit me and cure my illness.
>   Incidentally, I have heard that the Jews are grumbling about you and
>   wish you harm. I have a city, rather small, but noble, and it is
>   sufficient for us both.
>
> The Reply Of Jesus To King Abgar
>
> It is recorded that Jesus replied by means of a courier. He began the
>   letter by a saying that is found in John's gospel.
>
> ```
> Blessed are you, who has believed in me without having seen me.
> ```
>
> Jesus, according to His letter, declined Abgar's invitation because He
>   had not fulfilled His ministry. However, Jesus wrote that He would
>   send one of His disciples after His ascension, "so that he may cure
>   your illness and give life to you and to those who are with you."

So I want confirmation.

I sort of wonder why we have many writings of Paul in the new testament and none of writing of Jesus himself? As if Jesus's rank is not high enough to have his note be part of scripture. Also it's unlikely that Jesus never wrote anything given that well, he obviously can read, and write, and pretty much anything.

Comment: -1 because "*This question does not show any research effort […]*" (citation from the downvote tooltip)

Comment: There is a tradition of Jesus writing to this one king (I think it was king, but I may be wrong) who wanted to be healed. Jesus said he would send one his disciples after he left Earth. It has been a while since I read about this, so the details are blurry.

Answer (score 8):

Although the gospel accounts generally evidence the fact that Jesus was [fully literate](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/14680/1619), including this account in John:

> <sup>6</sup>This they said to test him, that they might have some charge to bring against him. Jesus bent down and **wrote with his finger on the ground**. <sup>7</sup>And as they continued to ask him, he stood up and said to them, “Let him who is without sin among you be the first to throw a stone at her.” <sup>8</sup>And once more he bent down and **wrote on the ground**. <sub><sub>[John 8, ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/john8.6-8)</sub></sub>

(While [the earliest manuscripts do not include 7:53–8:11](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%207&version=ESV#fen-ESV-26370g), the account still stands as evidence that the idea that Jesus was *able* to write was not at all controversial in early times.)

Other passages speak of Jesus learning, wisdom and familiarity with the writings, from an early age, for example:

- > <sup>46</sup>After three days they found him in the temple, sitting among the teachers, listening to them and asking them questions. <sup>47</sup>And all who heard him were amazed **at his understanding and his answers**. <sub><sub>[Luke 2, ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/luke+2%3A46-47)</sub></sub>
- > <sup>52</sup>And Jesus increased in wisdom and in stature and in favor with God and man. <sub><sub>[Luke 2, ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/luke+2%3A52)</sub></sub>
- > <sup>3</sup>And Jesus answered them, “**Have you not read** what David did when he was hungry, he and those who were with him: <sub><sub>[Luke 6, ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/luke+6%3A3)</sub></sub>
- > <sup>4</sup>He answered, “**Have you not read** that he who created them from the beginning made them male and female, <sub><sub>[Matthew 19, ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/mat+19.4)</sub></sub>

Jesus mission as explained in the gospel accounts does not include making a written account of his teachings, indeed he makes it clear that there is no need for him to do so:

> <sup>25</sup>“These things **I have spoken** to you while I am still with you. <sup>26</sup>But the Helper, the Holy Spirit, whom the Father will send in my name, he will teach you all things and **bring to your remembrance all that I have said** to you. <sub><sub>[John 14, ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/john+14.25-26)</sub></sub>

This is in contrast with (for example) Peter's stated aim in writing to fellow believers<sup><sup>1</sup></sup>:

> <sup>12</sup>Therefore I intend **always to remind you** of these qualities, though you know them and are established in the truth that you have. <sup>13</sup>I think it right, as long as I am in this body, to stir you up by way of reminder, <sup>14</sup>since I know that **the putting off of my body will be soon**, as our Lord Jesus Christ made clear to me. <sup>15</sup>And I will **make every effort** so that **after my departure you may be able at any time to recall these things**. <sub><sub>[ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/2pet+1%3A12-15)</sub></sub>

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> *It's my belief that this is the ongoing fulfillment of the [mission Peter received from Jesus](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=mark%201:17&version=ESV)*</sub>